# Closure of open line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to show that the closure of $(0, 1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just $[0,1]$. Intuitively this is obvious, but I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to do this directly from the definition. I want to prove the inclusion $\overline{(0, 1)} \subset [0, 1]$ (the other direction is easy), which means I want to show that if $x \not \in [0, 1]$, then there exists $r > 0$ such that $N_r(x) \cap (0, 1) = \emptyset$. Again, this is easy to picture in my head but I would like some help saying this in words. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is use the picture in your head to determine how big the disk can be. If I gave you an $(x, y)$, what is the closest point in $[0,1]$ to this point? This should involve casework on whether $x<0, x \in[0,1],$ or $x>1$. What is the distance from $(x,y)$ to this point? Now try to write down the algebra.

Comment: Let (x,y) so that $x \ne 0$.  Let $\epsilon < |x|$.  Then let $|x|= \epsilon > ||(a,b),(x,y)|| = \sqrt{(a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2} \ge \sqrt{(a-x)^2 }= |a - x|$ hence $a \ne 0$ so (x,y) is not limit point of (0,1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*: If a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ does not belong to $[0,1]$ on the $x$-axis, then at least one of the following holds:

1. the $x$-coordinate of the point is less than $0;$
2. the $x$-coordinate of the point is greater than $1;$

or 3. the $y$-coordinate of the point is not equal to $0.$

In any of these cases, it's easy to find an $r\gt 0$ such that $N_r(x) \cap (0, 1) = \emptyset.$

Comment: Ah, thinking in terms of x and y axes makes it much simpler. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0$ be an element of the closure of $(0,1)$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $(0,1)$ such that $x_n \to x_0$. From $0<x_n<1$ for all $n$, we see: $0 \le x_0 \le 1$